# Why is mapbox rejecting my geojson as invalid.

Tags: json, reactjs, parsing, mapbox, geojson

I have a function which is parsing JSON provided by the foursquare api to GeoJSON, which I then provide to the MapBox API using `JSON.stringify()` on the GeoJSON object then loading it to the map with the following code

MapBox API returns saying that my GeoJSON is invalid.

I checked the GeoJSON specification and it matches exactly !

Can anybody spot the error ?

loading function

```
this.map.on("load", () => {
  this.map.addSource("venues", {
    type: "geojson",
    data: geojson
  });
```

GeoJSON

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    { "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [48.31272484668867, 18.092948926236698]
      },
      "properties": {
        "id": "4d0a6cc933d6b60c1c569a85",
        "venueName": "Peciatkaren",
        "address": "Kmetkova 32",
        "distance": 20119,
        "icon": {
          "iconUrl": "../assets/img/dot_PNG41.png",
          "iconSize": [25, 25],
          "iconAnchor": [0, 0]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [48.30957732182106, 18.087218856597]
      },
      "properties": {
        "id": "4bd5ad37637ba5933bc3f670",
        "venueName": "Zanzibar",
        "address": "Štefánikova trieda 43",
        "distance": 20030,
        "icon": {
          "iconUrl": "../assets/img/dot_PNG41.png",
          "iconSize": [25, 25],
          "iconAnchor": [0, 0]
        }
      }
    }]
}
```

Comment: I think there is something wrong with how I am calling the mapbox API

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with your GeoJSON and there are several ways how you could use it.

Docs:

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#geojsonsource

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#sources-geojson

One example below:

```
var yourgeojson = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    { "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [48.31272484668867, 18.092948926236698]
      },
      "properties": {
        "id": "4d0a6cc933d6b60c1c569a85",
        "venueName": "Peciatkaren",
        "address": "Kmetkova 32",
        "distance": 20119,
        "icon": {
          "iconUrl": "../assets/img/dot_PNG41.png",
          "iconSize": [25, 25],
          "iconAnchor": [0, 0]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [48.30957732182106, 18.087218856597]
      },
      "properties": {
        "id": "4bd5ad37637ba5933bc3f670",
        "venueName": "Zanzibar",
        "address": "Štefánikova trieda 43",
        "distance": 20030,
        "icon": {
          "iconUrl": "../assets/img/dot_PNG41.png",
          "iconSize": [25, 25],
          "iconAnchor": [0, 0]
        }
      }
    }]
};

map.on('load', function () {

map.addSource('someid', {
    type: 'geojson',
    data: yourgeojson
});

map.addLayer({
        "id": "points",
        "type": "symbol",
        "source": "someid",
        "layout": {
            ...
        }
    });
});
```